# Axios GET request returning ECONNRESET for some URLs

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am working on an application that uses an express server to reach out to an API to fetch data. In our organisation outbound traffic requires a proxy which I have supplier to axios like below (not the real one):

```
let response = await axios.get(endpointUrl, {
    proxy: {
        host: "123.45.678.90",
        port: 0000,
    },
})
```

Passing various URLs into the axios get function returns varied results, with the following URLs returning a result:

- https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity
- https://api.ipify.org?format=json
- https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1

Whereas the following URLs are returning an ECONNRESET error almost instantly:

- https://api.publicapis.org/entries
- https://randomuser.me/api/
- https://reqres.in/api/users

I can't see any pattern between the URLs that are/are not working so wondered if a fresh set of eyes could spot the trait in them? It's important to note that all these URLs return successfully in the browser, just through this axios call being the problem.

To add to the mystery, the URLs that do work work on my machine, do work on a machine outside our organisation - so potentially a clue there?

Any help/guidance of course would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `ECONNRESET` is likely occurring either because the proxy runs into some sort of error and drops the connection or the target host finds something wrong with the incoming connection and decides to immediately drop it.  That target host may either be finding a problem because of the proxy or it may be expecting something in the request that it finds is missing.

Comment: FYI, all of these URLs seem to work just fine for me with `axios.get()` without a specific proxy so perhaps the issue is with the proxy.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, I believe you're correct regarding the proxy being an issue. I'll dive a bit deeper with it and see what could be blocking. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ECONNRESET is likely occurring either because the proxy runs into some sort of error and drops the connection or the target host finds something wrong with the incoming connection and decides to immediately drop it.

That target host may either be finding a problem because of the proxy or it may be expecting something in the request that it finds is missing.

Since you have evidence that all the requests work fine when running from a different location (not through your proxy) and I can confirm that your code works fine from my location (also not running through your proxy), it definitely seems like the evidence points at your proxy as causing some problem in some requests.

One way to debug proxy issues like this is to run a request through the proxy that ends up going to some server you can debug on and see exactly what the proxy has done to the incoming request, compared to a request to that same host that doesn't go through the proxy.  That will hopefully highlight some difference that you can then test to see if that's causing the problem and then eventually work on the configuration of the proxy to correct.

Answer (score 1):

If the URL that work on your machine also work outside your organization and the other don't, it is most likely a problem with your proxy.

Some proxies might have configurations that makes them remove headers or change the request in a way that the target does not receive it as intended.

I also encountered a problem with axios and proxies once. I had to switch libs to make it work. To be sure, I would recommand using a lib like "request" (deprecated) juste to make sure it is not a problem with axios. There are multiple open issues on the axios repository for proxy issues.

Answer (score 0):

This error simply means that the other party closed the connection in a way that was probably not normal (or perhaps in a hurry).

For example, a socket connection may be closed by the other party abruptly for various reasons or you may have lost your wifi signal while running your application. You will then see this error/exception on your end.

What could also be the case: at random times, the other side is overloaded and simply kills the connection as a result. If that's the case, depends on what you're connecting to exactly…

Solution - This is happening because you are not listening to/handling the 'error' event. To fix this, you need to implement a listener that can handle such errors.